# How to disable tty1 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and login normally?

Tags: tty

I was removing kde plasma environment through synaptic package manager and it's very likely that some of Ubuntu package were also removed. Since then I'm stuck at login loop. Sudo command were disabled which I was able to fix after some googling. I was also able to connect to wifi and got package updation completed. But now nothing works, not even able to connect to wifi by the previous method.

Comment: Hi and welcome. If this is a fairly new install I would blow it away and start fresh. You can spend weeks trying to fix this kind of issue and it will never be quite right.

Comment: I have important data. Will I lose that If I start fresh or is there anyway to save?

Comment: Yes you would boot from live media and copy to another USB first.

Comment: Maybe a short explaination [what tty1 through tty7 are](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293944/ctrl-alt-f7-shortcut/1293952#1293952) would be helpful. So the task would not be to disable tty1, but to restore your graphic user interface. But I'd agree with David: Copy all data you want to keep to an external medium (USB or such) and do a reinstall.