# after update ubuntu show me error in boot?

Tags: boot, bios, disk

**after update ubnutu and restart system show me this error in boot...**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7OsH.jpg

Comment: That is not an error; it's a `fsck` or file-system check message, most likely because the box was uncleanly shutdown in the prior session (ie. caused possibly by you using power-off button instead of a clean shutdown; ie. SysRq keys or other for your *unstated* OS/release)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but I've explained what this message means [in this answer to another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293944/ctrl-alt-f7-shortcut/1293952#1293952).

Comment: it show exactly what it say sda/dev x clean(no errors found in your file system).

Answer (score 0):

Does this line change over time?

It's seems your problem is similar to the one in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w).

Have you tried those steps?

Comment: This is not an answer it is and comment and should have been posted as such.

Comment: yes i tried this stepas , but not work for me